# How fetch latest <b> tag response in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So this is my bot : https://www.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=b3a17e933e345861

And I am trying to fetch current human vs thanos response so I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
browser=driver.get('https://www.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=b3a17e933e345861')
ask=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input')
inpu_1='ask thanos '
ask.send_keys(inpu_1)
time.sleep(2)
```

But now I am stuck and not able to find a way to fetch current human and thanos response because there are many  tag and if I try with xpath it looks like this:

/html/body/b[2]

So if I am trying this:

```
print(" thanos: {} ".format(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("b:contains('thanos:')")))
```

then it's not giving anything and returning blank

How to fetch latest reply of thanos?

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the `HTML DOM` the last `human response` is always on the `top` with the last `thanos response` following it. So as per your question to `find a way to fetch current human and thanos response` you can use the following code block :

```
full_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").get_attribute("innerHTML")
one_set_conversation = full_text.split("Human:")
human_thanos = one_set_conversation[1].split("thanos:")
print("Last Human Reply :")
print(human_thanos[0])
print("Last Thanos Reply :")
print(human_thanos[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just retrieve the body content and work on the text content:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
browser=driver.get('https://www.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=b3a17e933e345861')
ask=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input')
inpu_1='ask thanos '
ask.send_keys(inpu_1)
ask.submit()
content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').text.split("\n")
print(content)
time.sleep(2)
```

This code prints:

```
['Tell thanos:', '  Powered by Pandorabots.', '', 'Human: ask thanos', 'thanos: They are not available right now, but I will ask them later.']
```

So the latest response should be the 5th element of that list.

Comment: What a coincidence , that i did :P but i used driver.page_source